# Concatenation in Column X of a Google Sheet, based in Column Y

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with addresses(talking about real life, street addresses) on one column, and status on those addresses (like VACANT, EVICTION, OCCUPIED) on another. I'm trying to create a formula that will allow me to make a new column with a concatenation of the address + a specific tag based on the status. For example, if I have address "11423 Whisper Sound Drive, FL", with the status "OCCUPIED", I wanna have another column that says "11423 Whisper Sound Drive, FL < green-dot >"

My current approach isn't working, I'm getting a parse error:

```
= function letsDoThis() {
var addressValue = getCell(D2);
var statusValue = getCell(G2);
  if (statusValue == "OCCUPIED")
  {
    var newValue = addressValue + " <green-dot>";
    getCell(O2).setValue(newValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Comment: Thanks, your idea let me figure it out for myself, i changed it a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following formula based solution:

Try the following formula in cell O2:

```
=if(G2="OCCUPIED";D2&" <green-dot>";)
```